# How to remove html tags from strings in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

programming newbie here :)

I'd like to print the prices from the website using BeautifulSoup. this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = "Some retailer's url"
html = urlopen(url).read()
product = SoupStrainer('span',{'style': 'color:red;'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parse_only=product)
print soup.prettify()
```

and it prints prices in the following order:

```
<span style="color:red;">
 180
</span>
<span style="color:red;">
 1250
</span>
<span style="color:red;">
 380
</span>
```

I tried `print soup.text.strip()` but it returned `1801250380`

Please help me to print the prices per single row :)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> print "\n".join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in soup.find_all(product)])
180
1250
380
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you a list of strings converted to integers:

```
>>> [int(span.text) for span in soup.find_all('span')]
[180, 1250, 380]
```

Comment: This will stop working if the markup changes from `span` to, let's say, `div`.

Comment: So you are saying that if the code structure changes, the web scraping code needs to be updated? That should go without saying.